# Print 10 elements out of array

Tags: perl

If i have an array that I've used to create 50 random numbers, I then sort them numerically. Now lets say I wanted to print out the 10 biggest number (elements 40 to 50) I could say:

`print($array[40]) print($array[41]) print($array[42])` etc etc.
But is there a neater way to it? Hope I'm making myself clear.

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

You could loop over the indexes.

```
say $array[$_] for 40..49;
```

Offsets from the end make more sense here.

```
say $array[$_] for -10..-1;
```

You could also use an array slice.

```
say for @array[-10..-1];
```

To print them on one line, you can use `join`.

```
say join ', ', @array[-10..-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
print  join ',',@array[-10..-1] ,"\n";
```